# Error on npm install AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/pemrouz/buble.git

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm

[image]

Facing the above error, have set git proxy and its up to date not sure what is the issue
done reinstalling new github and deleted and cloned the project in new location but still getting this error

Comment: It's a name-lookup error. What name server are you using? Can you reach that name server from your computer?

Comment: I am not sure what is the name server and how to reach can you help ?

Comment: [consider starting here](https://superuser.com/q/320042/941003)